# Event for Geolocation Changed in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is there any event for the geolocation changed in Windows Phone 8 (C#)?
I want to trigger some event when the geolocation is changed like city from reversegeocoding changed.
If not, then is it possible to call some event manually whenever the Phone's location like City is Changed.
(suppose I have fetched the city using reverse geocoding). (for Windows Phone 8)

Comment: How does [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj247548(v=vs.105).aspx) not answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand your question properly, But this answer may solve your problem.

There is a event called "PositionChanged" in geolocator. This event gets triggered when geolocator position is changed.

```
 geolocator = new Geolocator();
 geolocator.PositionChanged -= geolocator_PositionChanged;

void geolocator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        LatitudeTextBlock.Text = args.Position.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString("0.00");
        LongitudeTextBlock.Text = args.Position.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString("0.00");
    });
}
```

for more info :::http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj247548(v=vs.105).aspx